# Hover in css covering menu above it

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu with a drop down that works nicely but the issue I noticed is if you hover a link with a child element, it opens the menu, but the link then become unclickable on the menu on the bottom half.

```
<div class="desktop_navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2 child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That's the structure for the menu. The child elements are sub `<ul>` of the main `<li>` and then hidden using CSS until their parent `<li>` is hovered.

The following jFiddle will include all the CSS I am using and a working example of the issue I am currently having:

https://jsfiddle.net/nrzfa49s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.desktop_navigation ul li ul` is inheriting the `padding-top: 30px` from its parent `ul` (`.desktop_navigation ul`) which is covering the parent link (Link 2) making it unclickable.

To fix your problem, update these styles:

```
.desktop_navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 0; /*remove the 30px padding*/
}

.desktop_navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /*set your top value to be more dynamic based on the height of the parent*/
    z-index: 890;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/endeLaak/1/) demoing this solution.

Normally when you style menus like this it is recommended to use the `>` when styling menu elements because of the nesting (i.e. `.desktop_navigation > ul` this will prevent the child `ul` from inheriting the padding)

Answer (score 1):

Took some time, but the issue is here:

```
.desktop_navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 30px; //remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want the `padding-top` for the `ul`'s to be on the parent/top-level menu. Then if you remove the `top` attribute from the nested menus, they will display after the link in the top-level menu.

```css
.desktop_navigation a {
 color: #ccc;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 12px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
 background: #444;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 1002;
 padding: 12px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li ul li a:link,
.desktop_navigation ul li ul li a:visited,
.desktop_navigation ul li ul li a:active {
 z-index: 1001;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 color: #444;
 background: #fff;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li ul li a:hover {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 color: #111;
 z-index: 1002;
 background: #ccc;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.desktop_navigation ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.desktop_navigation > ul {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 z-index: 1002;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: none;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 890;
}

.desktop_navigation ul li ul li {
 float: none; 
 position: relative;
 min-width: 180px;
 z-index: 890;
}
```

```html
     <div class="desktop_navigation">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#asdf">Link 2 child</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```